# How to return to the last redacted place in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, hotkeys

How I can return to the last redacted place via hot keys in sublime text 2?
I know about Emmet's possibility, but I want to do this in any document type.
Any suggestion?

Comment: It' been a while since I used Sublime but I _think_ it was Alt-Minus. Try it out.

Comment: @SolarBear I tried just, but unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: Ah it's not quite it, it only works with the `Goto Definition` feature, it's not quite what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a much requested (and thus, missing) feature to Sublime. [See this feature request](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/60649-move-to-last-edit-location/direction-down/). Read the comments, some user have come up with workarounds and scripts to fill the missing functionality, such as [this one](https://github.com/ktaragorn/ChangeList/tree/all_files).

Comment: My pleasure! If you find a script/workaround you're happy with, make sure to share it with us.

Comment: I have tried that workaround script, and it work perfectly as for me. It is easy and useful. So thanks a lot again!